# How can I figure out which gate I am departing from in Dubai international airport?

Tags: transit, dxb, emirates

I'm traveling from Oslo to Bangkok, with a connection at Dubai international airport. Do I need to do anything before boarding my connecting flight (i.e check in, security check, etc.)?

How can I figure out which gate I am departing from in Dubai international airport?

Both my flight from Oslo to Dubai and my connecting flight from Dubai to Bangkok are Emirates flights.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you'll figure out your boarding gate in Oslo: looking at your boarding pass, and the electronic signboards, is always a good idea...

If you get both boarding passes in Oslo (possible since it's Emirates flights), the gate might not be yet printed on the second boarding pass. In which case, you'll have to check in Dubai, on the numerous information boards. Or if you get the second boarding pass only in Dubai, at the transfer desk, then it will be printed on the boarding pass (most probably, unless you have a long layover). And the information boards will still be there to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It will help me a lot.  I was just worried to figure out my gate, and how to get to it, after all it is the worlds largest airport.

Comment: Follow the signs.  It may be one of the largest airports in the world, but it's also one of the easier ones to get around.  (I'm sitting here right now watching planes depart from DXB out my hotel window!)